# Openlayers3: Abort the Draw Interaction

Tags: jquery, html, css, openlayers-3

i am using for my html a draw interaction for drawing routes manually

```
// manual route creation event
            $('#createRoute').click(function() {
                // remove previous interactions
                map.removeInteraction(draw);

                // create linestring interaction
                draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    source: routeSource,
                    type: ('LineString'),

                })

                // add interaction to map
                map.addInteraction(draw);

                draw.on('drawstart', function(event) {
                    console.log("Map Interaction(Route): activated");
                });

                draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
                    saveRoute(event);
                    map.removeInteraction(draw);

                    console.log("Map Interaction(Route): deactivated");
                  });
            });
```

and asking for a name in this function

```
// saving a route as defined route-object
            function saveRoute(event) {
                // saving ol.objects
                var feature = event.feature;
                var lineString = feature.getGeometry();
                var newWaypoints = lineString.getCoordinates();

                // setting tempid in case of abortion
                feature.setId("tempID");

                // prompt popup for routeName
                var routeName = prompt("Name der Route eingeben", "");
                var newName;

                // save route object
                if (routeName != null && routeName.length > 0) {
                    newName = routeName;

                    console.log(routeName);
                    console.log(newWaypoints);
                }else
                {
                    console.log("Route creation aborted");
                }
            }
```

if the user aborts the prompt or enters no name, how can i stop the interaction/delete the linestring which has been created?
I tried it by defining a unique tempID and delete it from the source but this doesnt seem to work..

Comment: don't forget to give some feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Wait until your feature is [added](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.VectorEvent.html#event:addfeature) to `ol.source.Vector`:

```
your_source.on('addfeature', function(event) {
    saveRoute(event);
    map.removeInteraction(draw);

    console.log("Map Interaction(Route): deactivated");
});
```