# Openlayers 3 remove drawn feature

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

**I am adding "draw interaction" and drawing features on a map...**

```
 webMapValues.drawObj = new ol.interaction.Draw({                                
                            features: features,
                            type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (webMapValues.drawType)

                        });
```

**I am catching the "drawend" event...**

```
 webMapValues.drawObj.on('drawend', function (e) {                            

                        //Here I am saving my feature to a data base
                          and displaying the saved vector...
                        control.UpdateObjects(e, "Draw");

                        //Here I would like to remove the vector that
                          draw interaction placed and just display the 
                          vector from the db


                    });
```

I can not figure out how to remove the vector that ol.interaction.Draw has placed so that only the vector from the data base shows after I save it?

I guess 'drawend' is not the place to do this...but I'm not sure how to achieve the functionality I need then...

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code of `ol.interaction.Draw()` interaction`drawend` is called before the feature gets inserted to the `ol.source`.

`finishDrawing()` method  will insert the feature object.

Below is the snippet from the latest [sourcecode](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/draw.js)

> /**  * Stop drawing and add the sketch feature to the target layer.
>
> The {@link ol.interaction.DrawEventType.DRAWEND} event is dispatched
>   before  * inserting the feature.  * @api  */
>
> ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.finishDrawing = function() {

So you can not delete the feature in the `drawend` event.  The above code snippet is self explanatory.

Comment: So how can I achieve the desired behavior?  can I somehow call finishDrawing and stop the sketch feature from being drawn?

Comment: Funn_Bobby, the better approach would be to wait until its added to the source, then remove it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798891/openlayers3-abort-the-draw-interaction

Answer (score 0):

```
function noDraw() {

  if (draw) {
        map.removeInteraction(webMapValues.drawObj);
  }


};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by listening to the "addfeature" event to immediately remove the added feature if the feature has the key "removeMe"

```
  yourVectorSource.on("addfeature", (event) => {
    if (event.feature.get("removeMe")) {
      this.source.removeFeature(event.feature);
    }
  });
  webMapValues.drawObj.on('drawend', function (e) {        
    control.UpdateObjects(e, "Draw");
    
    //add removeMe key now!
    e.feature.set("removeMe",true);
  });
```